# libpq-fe.h and c program closing

Tags: c, postgresql, libpq

I've got a problem with a C program that connects with localhost database on postgresql. Code looks similar to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libpq-fe.h>

int main() {

int dane;
PGconn *dbh; // definujemy uchwyt do bazy – jest to specjalna zmienna pamiętająca
PGresult *wynik ; //wskaźnik do struktury przechowującej wynik zapytania 

dbh = PQconnectdb("dbname=lab1 user=postgres");
// teraz sprawdźmy statud połączenia:
if (PQstatus(dbh) == CONNECTION_OK)
{

  printf("Jest polaczenie z baza \n");
// tu będziemy wpisywali całą obsluge bazy danych
wynik = PQexec(dbh,"INSERT INTO osoba(imie,nazw) VALUES('Jan','Kowalski')");
// wyswietlmy status z serwera
//printf(„%s\n”,PQresStatus(wynik));

switch(PQresultStatus(wynik))
{
    case PGRES_TUPLES_OK:
    // jeśli zapytanie zwroci dane to tutaj je sprawdzimy
    break;
    case PGRES_COMMAND_OK:
    // nie ma danych
    printf("Zapytanie sie powiodlo \n");
    break;
    case PGRES_EMPTY_QUERY:
    printf ("Serwer nie mial nic do roboty , moze blad ?\n");
    break;
    case PGRES_NONFATAL_ERROR:
    printf("Blad niekrytyczny, sprobuj ponowic zapytanie\n");
    break;
    case PGRES_FATAL_ERROR:
    default:
    printf("Blad krytyczny \n");
    // wyswietlmy status bledu
    printf("%s\n",PQresultErrorMessage(wynik));
}

// wyczyscmy wynik o ile jest
PQclear(wynik);
// teraz rozłączmy sie z bazą
PQfinish(dbh);

} else { printf("No connection..\n"); }

getch();
return 0;

}
```

When I run this program it's automically closing without any prompt. I can't stop this with anything, like getch(), getchar() or system("PAUSE"). When I delete everything above variables declaration program runs okay. What's the issue?

Comment: Does your program give any output? Run it from a terminal/dos prompt if you don't get a chance to read it.

Comment: When I try to run from cmd.exe it gives error - can't read dll library..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required DLL's are all located in the bin folder of your postgresql install. Typically c:\program files\postgresql\9.0\bin

These DLL's have to be in the search path or in the same folder as your executable. The relevant DLL's are: COMERR32.DLL, GSSAPI32.DLL, K5SPRT32.DLL, KRB5_32.DLL, LIBEAY32.DLL, LIBICONV2.DLL, LIBINTL3.DLL, LIBPQ.DLL and SSLEAY32.DLL.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest stepping through the code with a debugger.

Failing that, load it with appropriate print statements.  For example:

```
int main()
{
    PGconn *dbh = PQconnectdb("dbname=lab1 user=postgres");
    fputs("After PQconnectdb()\n", stderr);
    int status = PQstatus(dbh);  // C99
    fputs("After PQstatus()\n");
    if (status == CONNECTION_OK)
    {
        PGresult *wynik = PQexec(dbh,"INSERT INTO osoba(imie,nazw) VALUES('Jan','Kowalski')");
        fputs("After PQexec()\n", stderr);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Using `fputs()` to `stderr` usually ensures that the messages are not buffered, so you see them even if the program crashes; this does not always happen with writing to `stdout`.

I'm assuming `PQstatus()` returns an integer since the values are used in a `switch` statement.

Comment: okay i tried that and it shows that i don't have libpq.dll on my machine, maybie you can tell me how to properly include libpq-fe library at dev cpp?

Comment: @Kamil: I don't know how to install PostgreSQL on Windows.  Go to the [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) web site to find out.